# Plugin firebase_messaging could not be built due to the issue above

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Here I am getting the above error. here when I am trying to run flutter build `apk` then it will show me to the above error. I've used firebase for my project simple push notification. but when I am trying to build `apk` it causes an issue with firebase

```
   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':device_info:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\rutvi\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\02e40ce8e8ac3f0fe1e2835a9dad7bf0\core-1.0.1\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

     C:\Users\rutvi\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\02e40ce8e8ac3f0fe1e2835a9dad7bf0\core-1.0.1\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 41s
```

Here are Packages that I've used in the project. you can see here, there are no Connectivity_macos packages

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_bloc: ^0.20.0
  equatable: ^0.4.0
  font_awesome_flutter:
  loader_search_bar: ^1.0.3+3
  image_picker:
  curved_navigation_bar: ^0.1.26
  flutter_speed_dial: ^1.2.1
  dynamic_theme: ^1.0.1
  flutter_redux: ^0.5.3
  redux: ^3.0.0
  redux_persist_flutter: ^0.8.2
  redux_logging: ^0.3.0
  graphql_flutter: ^2.1.1-beta.5
  device_info: ^0.2.1
  flutter_masked_text: ^0.8.0
  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
  datetime_picker_formfield:
  flutter_form_builder:
  pin_code_text_field: ^1.2.1
  pin_code_fields: ^1.1.1
  google_map_location_picker: ^2.1.0
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl:
  intl_translation:
  http_parser: ^3.1.3
  cached_network_image: 2.0.0-rc
  dio: ^3.0.4
  sqflite: ^1.1.7+2
  path_provider: ^1.4.0
  argon_buttons_flutter: ^1.0.2
  keyboard_actions: ^3.0.0
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.0
  barcode_scan: ^1.0.0
  awesome_dialog: ^0.1.0
  table_calendar: ^2.2.2
  flutter_multiselect: ^0.4.0
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.9

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: You may have that package in your pubspec.yaml file. Try flutter clean.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya no I don't have that packages in my pubspec and I've also tried after flutter clean but still same issue

Comment: Can you add all packages you are using?

Comment: I've updated the question please have a look

Comment: After solving above issue I am getting this error `plugin firebase_messaging could not be built due to the issue above`.

Comment: i also have the same problem with the app that im trying to upload on console. this problem can be solve by building app bundle instead of app if u r uploading to play console. cmd - flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64

Comment: is there any other solution?? which I can use for build release APK

Answer (score 1):

You should try with below steps. It may solve your problem.

**Workaround Steps:**

In Android Studio (with your project open) right click the android folder, and click "Flutter"->"Open Android Module in Android Studio". Select "Open in New Window"

In the new window, expand "Gradle Scripts"

Locate "build.gradle (Module: device_info)".

In the gradle scripts, modify the compileSdkVersion from 27->28.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with package `firebase_message`, I edited version to: `firebase_messaging: 1.0.2`